# Define custom folder while installing nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a special folder structure within solution as below

abc.sln
|
------>Resource
       |
       ------->*.dll

I want to install the package (.nupkg) inside resource folder directly rather than \lib\netXX*.dll

How can we ignore/remove/avoid ("lib\netXX") folder while installing package

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to the expand path of packages using the [repository path property](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file) in nuget.config.